# MergedDictionaries and Shared styles across assemblies

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Perhaps somebody will help me out. I have been trying all day to find a solution for sharing styles and resources on my WindowsPhone project.

The problems is the following:

I have a common assembly which is used by two WP projects. Inside this assembly I have some styles and datatemplates defined. I want one of the datatemplates to be defined in the common assembly and be the default datatemplate for the projects.

Assembly resource dictionary sample code:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TopItemsTitle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe WP Black"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TopItemsTemplate">
    <Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Name"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Width="172"
                   Height="25"
                   Margin="0,6,0,50"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Style="{StaticResource TopItemsTitle}" />
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Inside the different project I would like to redefine the TopItemsTitle style, for example:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TopItemsTitle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe WP"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
</Style>
```

and then merge both resource dictionaries in the app.xaml of one the WP projects:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assembly;component/Resources/Style.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/LocalStyle.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) this should be possible. However in reality this does not work. The datatemplate does not reflect the redefined style and uses the default one.

Is this a bug or am I simple do it wrong?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the article.  Looking up a `StaticResource` always starts at the element and then walks up the tree.

`TopItemsTemplate` is defined in the common `Style.xaml`, so any `{StaticResource}` reference in the template will first look for a match in `Button` (none found), then the `DataTemplate` (none found), then the `ResourceDictionary` of `Style.xaml` (found).  If there was nothing found in `Style.xaml`, only then would it continue to try to find one in the merged dictionary.

If you move the `TopItemsTitle` to a different dictionary (so the merged dictionary has 3 sources instead of 2), it may work, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you @RobSiklos, you were right moving the TopItemsTitle style to a different dictionary solved the problem. 
Actually I found something else, you do not need to define the style on the common style.xaml dictionary you can define it locally per application on their respective LocalStyle.xaml dictionaries.